# Group JSON object using key in python

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, iteration, key-value

I have have JSON data as given below,

```
{
  "BLE:ble_type1": "xx",
  "BLE:ble_mac1": "yy",
  "BLE:ble_type2": "aa",
  "BLE:ble_mac2": "bb"
}
```

and the expected output is,

```
"BLE":[  
        {  
          "ble_type1":"xx",
          "ble_mac1":"yy"
        },
        {  
          "ble_type2":"aa",
          "ble_mac2":"bb"
        }
      ]
```

Can someone help me out in getting the required output using python?

Comment: There is no such function that works like you are expecting. You need to split this json and make as you want it by using for loop.

Comment: Thanks.yes i am able to achieve this,  "BLE":[  
      {  
         "type1":"reference",
         "mac1":"aa:dd:dd:dd:dd"  
         "type2":"environment",
         "mac2":"12:dd:ss:aa:ss"
      }
   ]

Comment: how are you reading the JSON data, from file or string? is it already stored in a variable, if so is its datatype `dict`?

Comment: @davedwards  the data is stored in a variable and yes the datatype is dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a starting point, works for the example given. Likely will need to adjust for other JSON input data:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {
  "BLE:ble_type1": "xx",
  "BLE:ble_mac1": "yy",
  "BLE:ble_type2": "aa",
  "BLE:ble_mac2": "bb"
}

od = OrderedDict(d.items())

mainkey = set([k.split(':')[0] for k in list(d.keys())]).pop()

keys = [k.split(':')[1] for k in od.keys()]
values = list(od.values())
print(keys)
data = []

count = int(keys[0][-1])

d = {}

for k, v in zip(keys, values):
  n = int(k[-1])

  if n == count:
    d[k] = v

  else:
    d = {}
    count += 1 
    if n == count:
      d[k] = v

  if d not in data:
    data.append(d)

new_d = {mainkey: data}
```

---

Now you have a new `dict` that contains the desired output:

```
>>> print(new_d)

{'BLE': [{'ble_type1': 'xx', 'ble_mac1': 'yy'}, {'ble_type2': 'aa', 'ble_mac2': 'bb'}]}
```

We can verify this matches the desired output:

```
>>> desired = [  
        {  
          "ble_type1":"xx",
          "ble_mac1":"yy"
        },
        {  
          "ble_type2":"aa",
          "ble_mac2":"bb"
        }
      ]

>>> print(new_d['BLE'] == desired)
True
```

Hope this helps. If it is not as you wanted, please leave a comment and will try to improve.

Comment: Thank you so much ..will check the code and get back to you.